# Referencing node/nid in hook_menu_local_tasks in Drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal

I'm working on theming an insurance system, where each product (for example MyInsuranceCompany) is saved as a node, with all tasks available for that product as menu_local_tasks. I want to be able to add a menu item in that will display the node title. So for example the list will read "MyInsuranceCompany, View, Edit, Documentation, Etc".

It sounds very simple but I can't work out how to do it. I've tried using arg() but that appears to return something completely unrelated about json; I tried setting a global variable in preprocess_node but I imagine the bootstrapping process isn't the right way round to do that. Not sure if it's an obvious solution that I'm missing but hopefully one of you lovely ladies & gents can help out! (If that's not buttering up I don't know what is!)

Hope I've explained myself well-
Thanks!
Matt

Comment: I don't think there is a "hook_menu_local_tasks". You add local tasks from your module's "hook_menu". Maybe you can play with the "title callback" to get what you want (take a look at node.module's hook_menu)

Comment: Thanks for the response- I'm referring to PHPtemplate's function. I guess I meant theme_menu_local_tasks(). My apologies!

Comment: I ended up solving the issue- took the functionality out of template.php and just printed $title in the page.tpl.php instead and it works fine. Thanks for taking the time though :)